# Exception with EmbeddedSolrServer : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to use the EmbeddedSolrServer with Solrj, but when I run my program, I get an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.                                                                             java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces                                                                             sorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa                                                                             der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/Resou                                                                             rceLoader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14                                                                             2)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14                                                                             2)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:35)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.Res                                                                             ourceLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 28 more
```

I've seen another post that shows the same problem but I didn't understand how to set the classpath they've talked about.

I've got the solr-core-4.2.1.jar. I checked that this JAR file contains ResourceLoader Class and it does. So I'm a bit lost... Why this class is missing when I run my program ?

Posts related to my problem :

[solr java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/common/ResourceLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018765/solr-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-solr-common-resourceloader)

**Edit :** [I'm trying to index files in a document through SOLR and lucene..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245202/im-trying-to-index-files-in-a-document-through-solr-and-lucene)

Could someone explain ?

Thanks

Corentin

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245202/im-trying-to-index-files-in-a-document-through-solr-and-lucene

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already saw this post but my problem is how to set this classpath. Do I need to change something in the solrconfig.xml or in my Java Program including this class ? 
I have found this class here : solr-4.3.0\lucene\analysis\common\src\java\org\apache\lucene\analysis\util\ResourceLoader.
What do I need to do with this file ?

Comment: how are you adding other jars ?? just find the jar mentioned in the answer and add it with the other jars.

Comment: I've added my other JARs with Eclipse doing Properties-> Java Build Path -> Add Externals JARs. After that I've generated an executable JAR of my Java Program. I think I don't use the right file because the ResourceLoader file I have found isn't a JAR file. Where can I find the lucene-analyzers-common-X.X.X.jar file ? Thank

Comment: That's fine ! I found it on this web site : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common 
I'll try. Thank you for your help :)